# Condition for deadlock to happen

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

Deadlock-

A deadlock is a situation in which two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does.

For deadlock to happen all these four conditions must hold simultaneously

1. Mutual exclusion
2. Hold and wait
3. No preemption
4. Circular wait

we apply deadlock detection algorithm to check whether the system is in deadlock or not. But if any of the above criterion fails(For example No preemption fails, so some resource is being released) which incur the system to be deadlock free. So what I think, if the deadlock detection algorithm finds the state to be unsafe and all the above four criterion holds true simultaneously then we can say the system is in deadlock.
Unsafe state may or may not lead to deadlock. 
But unsafe state with all these 4 conditions holding simultaneously must incur deadlock.

Am I thinking right?

I have another question in my mind. How can we say deadlock has occurred definitely because the next moment some process may release their resources to get rid of deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I thinking right?

Yes, you are correct.
See this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-unsafe-state-not-always-cause-deadlock) to see why unsafe may not lead to deadlock.

> I have another question in my mind. How can we say deadlock has occurred definitely because the next moment some process may release their resources to get rid of deadlock.

Say deadlock has occurred. All processes causing the deadlock are waiting for some resource to be acquired. And because of "No preemption" no such process will get preempted and therefore release resources. Also because of "Hold and wait" property, process needs some more resources to continue but is not going to give up or release whatever it is holding now and will wait till its required resources are met. Once there is deadlock, nothing can happen (there cannot be any progress) until you break one of the above condition. Breaking a condition will make some other process to meet its requirements and ensure progress and completion.

Comment: plz, can you also upvote the answer if the answer is to the point and sound?

Comment: From what I understand is, "Deadlock is a permanent blocking of a set of processes waiting for one another to release the resources". If there is no preemption, processes will voluntarily release the resources once they are done. So this should lead to starvation, not deadlock, right?

Comment: But no process is going to progress towards completion as it depends on some resource and they will be endlessly waiting for it as others are not ready to release. Therefore deadlock.